# tan function pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

In my code below (MWE), I do not get the dotted lines for the `tan` function and there is a weird tick at the bottom of the graph. Why is that the case and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
    xmin=-7,
    xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5,
    trig format=rad, %<- 
    xtick={-2*pi,-3*pi/2, -pi, -pi/2,pi/2,pi,3*pi/2,2*pi},
    xticklabels={$-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$},
    every axis y label/.style={rotate=0, black, at={(0.5,1.05)},},
    every axis x label/.style={rotate=0, black, at={(1.05,0.5)},},,
    font=\footnotesize,     
 ]
\addplot[samples=200,smooth]{tan(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `samples=201`.

Comment: Also for dotted lines you should add a `\draw` or another `\addplot` specifying start and end in order to tell LaTeX where you want to put these lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `tan` has poles in the domain, which causes these effects. Therefore, I'd rather plot the branches separately in a loop, and thus avoid the poles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=middle,
    axis on top,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
    xmin=-7,
    xmax=7,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=5,
    trig format plots=rad, %<- 
    xtick={-2*pi,-3*pi/2, -pi, -pi/2,pi/2,pi,3*pi/2,2*pi},
    xticklabels={$-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$},
    every axis y label/.style={rotate=0, black, at={(0.5,1.05)},},
    every axis x label/.style={rotate=0, black, at={(1.05,0.5)},},,
    font=\footnotesize,     
 ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-5,-3,...,3}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{ifthenelse(#1==-5,-2*pi,#1*pi/2+0.01)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{ifthenelse(#1==3,2*pi,#1*pi/2+pi-0.01)}
\addplot[samples=51,smooth,domain=\xmin:\xmax]{tan(x)};
\draw[densely dotted] (#1*pi/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
 -- (#1*pi/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please also note that I use `trig format plots=rad` rather than `trig format=rad`.